Connect to an RDS instance from VS Code
I´m using SQL Tools and SQL Tools PostgreSQL driver to connect to an RDS instance (AWS Academy Canvas Laboratory to testing). My security group looks like this:

I tried telnet command to test if I reach the port:

I also set in 0 rds.force_ssl on my new parameter group:

Credentials look like:

But I´m still unable to connect:

I´d be very thankful with your help.

Your RDS instance is configured to allow inbound traffic from any source (0.0.0.0/0) on port 5432. and this should technically work for allowing connections.
The error is indicating no-encryption, it may be because you're connecting without ssl if you use SSL in the connection, it will solve it instantly - disabling force_ssl might not align properly with your client settings or the RDS default behavior. Even when rds.force_ssl=0 is set, AWS RDS might still expect SSL connections unless explicitly disabled in your client tool. This is because many drivers, including PostgreSQL drivers, attempt to use SSL by default if they detect it is supported. you need to explicitly disable SSL in SQL Tools.
By default, many PostgreSQL drivers attempt to establish SSL connections. Disabling SSL locally ensures the driver aligns with the database configuration rds.force_ssl=0.
Also do not forget to reboot the RDS instance after adding rds.force_ssl=0, otherwise you'll have mismatch between the SQL tool and the RDS.

SSL is disabled in SQL Tools, in the image is shown.

issue with the pg_hba.conf, is that it's not configurable within the RDS, weird error if it's also disabled within the SQL tool

did you reboot the RDS after setting the rds.force_ssl=0 ???

when you try to connect to the RDS within an EC2 instance, do you get the same error? psql -h <RDS_ENDPOINT> -U postgres -d sam-oscar-company -p 5432
